# previous page tab disappeas after visiting the page without a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm new to ionic and i'm developing a tab based app. when the app loads for the first time the tabs are active and when the `User Account` link is clicked it takes you to a that page which doesn't have a tab, when you come back to the home page you get the home page tab disappeared.

meanwhile i've only applied the `hide-tabs` class to just one page

js

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

//mother tabs persistant on all pages that  is the tabs

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider){
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("standard");
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("standard");
    $stateProvider
    .state('tabs',{
        url: '/tab',
        abstract:true,
        templateUrl:'templates/index_tabs.html',

    })



     .state('tabs.index',{
        url:'/index',
        views:{
        'list-index':{
        templateUrl:  'templates/index_files/index.html',
        }
        }
    })

    .state('tabs.useracc',{
        url:'/useracc',
        views:{
        'list-useracc':{
        templateUrl:  'templates/index_files/useracc.html',
        }
        }
    })

    .directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $el) {
                $rootScope.hideTabs = true;
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
                });
            }
        };

    });
```

html

```
          <ion-list>
<ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" data-ng-controller="line_modal"  ng-click="line_modal()"> 
      <img src="img/index/social.png" alt="photo" width="64" height="64" />
      <h2>User Account</h2>
      <p>To have access to your line details, simply tap on the &quot;3 bars&quot; at the top right of your screen to access your line details </p>

          </ion-item>
   </ion-view>
```

tabs

```
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" title="Home" href="#/tab/index">
        <ion-nav-view name="list-index"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="ion-log-in" title="User Account" href="#/tab/login">
        <ion-nav-view name="list-login"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: can you please share your code app.js(routes) or push your code in github

Comment: @Anilkumar, i''ve just updated the question